# importing excel sheet into mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I want to import the excel sheet data into mysql table with php but i am getting these errors someone please get me out from this.. please look on php code only ignore html stuff.

```
<?php
    include ("connection.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $name = $filesop[1];
            $email = $filesop[2];

            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO co (name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')");

            $c = $c + 1;

        }
        fcose($file);

            if($sql){
                echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ." recoreds";
            }else{
                echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
            }

    }
?>
```

[this is excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llyX3.png)

[in database it is showing different format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNIrx.png)

Comment: It doesn't look like your file is saved in CSV format - you can't use `fgetcsv` to read Excel format files.

Comment: To import excel file to database you have to use some plugin like http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ otherwise here you have to save ur excel file to csv and import using this code,it will work

Comment: seems your file is sample1.csv, which is indeed correct format. Now, you are getting gibrish characters in database. Try setting the character set to utf8 before starting. For this run this query before everything once - SET NAMES utf8. Also, make sure the character set of your table, database is utf8

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries `excellibrary/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php` and `excellibrary/SpreadsheetReader.php`

you can use these libraries to read your content and convert it into array.
Once you convert your spreadsheet data into an array, you can easily insert into database using iterations.